# Accepting char(N) to exit calculator loop

Tags: c++, while-loop

I'm writing a very basic calculator program that loops and then exits when the user enters the character 'N'. I cannot seem to get the program to exit when 'N' is entered. I have breezed through all of the problems but I am having a problem incorporating this.

I'm already sure someone will say something about using `void main()`, this is what my instructor wants. I also know the condition for my while statement (`Num1 != 'N'`) is incorrect, it's just a placeholder for now as this is what I need help figuring out.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void main()
{
int Num1, Num2, Plus, Minus, Divide, Mod, Mult;
char Operand;


do
{
    cout << "Enter two separate integers ---> ";
    cin >> Num1 >> Num2;

    cout << "\nEnter desired operand ---> ";
    cin >> Operand;
    cout << endl;

    switch (Operand)
    {
    case '+':
        Plus = (Num1 + Num2);
        cout << Num1 << " + " << Num2 << " = " << Plus << endl;
        break;
    case '-':
        Minus = (Num1 - Num2);
        cout << Num1 << " - " << Num2 << " = " << Minus << endl;
        break;
    case '*':
        Mult = (Num1 * Num2);
        cout << Num1 << " * " << Num2 << " = " << Mult << endl;
        break;
    case '/':
        Divide = (Num1 / Num2);
        cout << Num1 << " / " << Num2 << " = " << Divide << endl;
        break;
    case '%':
        Mod = (Num1 % Num2);
        cout << Num1 << " % " << Num2 << " = " << Mod << endl;
        break;

    }


}
while (Num1 != 'N');
}
```

Comment: Have you tried `Operand != 'N'` instead?

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. This does work, but I wanted to allow the user to exit at anytime. I tried to do a "Enter (Y/N) to continue) type thing, but the program started to get whacky(for example, I got an error saying something along the lines of "Operand not defined etc...") and I wasn't sure what to set as the while condition

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Num1 is an integer and would never equal 'N'.
Instead try initializing a string buffer, then checking whether it begins with 'N'. Then follow up if true by exiting, otherwise convert the string to an integer. Your code could be better optimized as this:

```
int Num1, Num2, Plus, Minus, Divide, Mod, Mult;
char Operand;
string buffer;

while(true) {
    cout << "Enter two separate integers ---> ";
    cin >> buffer;
    if(buffer.at(0) == 'N') break;    /* Checks for 'N' as first char and breaks out */
    Num1 = atoi(buffer.c_str());      /* Sets Num1 to the integer value of buffer */
    cin >> Num2;
    cout << "\nEnter desired operand ---> ";
    cin >> Operand;
    cout << endl;

    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
while (Operand != 'N');
```

:)

Answer (score 0):

You main problem resided within the logic of the program. As in order to reach the `Num1 != 'N'` it requires you to input 3 characters at least. It would be more convenient if you check on the first cin or after any cin.

Also, it would be better if you check against 'n' as well, as you might not be pressing SHIFT.

Answer (score 0):

Well you said `Operand != 'N'` worked and you want it to work for all the input types.
My suggestion (Sorry my c++ is junk i know) is to read them one by one and branching after each read:

```
cin >> Num1;
if(Num1 == 'N')
 break;
cin >> Num2;
if(Num2 == 'N')
 break;
cin >> Operand;
if(Operand == 'N')
 break;
```

Or do so in a loop:

```
#define NUMBER_OF_INPUTS 3

for(int i=0 ; i<NUMBER_OF_INPUTS ; i++){
  cin >> input[i];
 if(input[i] == 'N')
  return;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you would be better off using a different variable to handle termination.  Using something like this:

```
do {
cout << "Do you want to continue (Y/N)?"
cin >> terminate;
if (terminate == 'N')
break;
//your code here
} while(terminate != 'N');
```